# How to group by date in queryset

Tags: json, django

I need help with writing proper queryset in Django View. I have `Post` model with `created_at` (`datetime` field). I want to group it by date and return in a specific format.

`models.py`

```
class Post(TrackableDate):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

`views.py`

```
class PostViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

`serializers.py`

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

The usual response looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "ok",
    "created_at": "2012-12-12T12:30:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "ok",
    "created_at": "2012-12-12T12:30:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "text": "ok",
    "created_at": "2012-12-13T12:30:00"
  }
]
```

How to group and return like that?

```
{
  "2012-12-12": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "ok",
      "created_at": "2012-12-12T12:30:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "ok",
      "created_at": "2012-12-12T12:30:00"
    }
  ],
  "2012-12-13": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "text": "ok",
      "created_at": "2012-12-13T12:30:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to do

`Post.objects.extra(select={'created_at': 'date(created_at)'}).values('created_at').annotate(available=Count('created_at'))`

But it returns

`<QuerySet [{'created_at': '2020-07-04', 'available': 7}, {'created_at': '2020-07-09', 'available': 2}]>`

Comment: so are you using DRF, or it is just a django view can you show us the view please?

Comment: @ThunderHorn thank you for your interest. I added all files. I'm using DRF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a helper function, you can accomplish your results like this, it may be a better solution. This is the one that I came up with

```
def group_by_date(mydata):
     new_data = {}
     for element in mydata:
         v = element['created_at'].split('T')[0]
             if v not in new_data.keys():
                 new_data[v] = []
         new_data[v].append(element)
     return new_data
```

You can override the get function of your API and rework the output

and override `return Response(group_by_date(serializer.data), HTTP_200_OK)`

Comment: It can be rewritten without a second loop